# how to implement high availability of mysql in windows?

Tags: mysql, high-availability

I have done MySQL master1-master2 replication in windows,is work nicely. but i have doubt how to manage data when master1 server  is down because master2 manage data on the basis of master1 log file,in this case when master1 is down there is no log updation is done. please help how to switch server on failure of another one in windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your case you have to manually do this by changing the IP address within your application which can be a big headache. Have you tried to use MYSQL cluster setup.